# Forcing keyboard to display when a text input is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7, keyboard

The scenario, I have an input text field I'm doing partial auto-complete on (exactly like the Tags input field on Stack Overflow... because that's what is, basically).

As a user is typing, I suggest things they may typing; the user then clicks one the suggestions, it replaces a bit of the fields content, and places the cursor after where the insert occurred.

All this works, *but* after the insertion the software keyboard isn't shown anymore.  You can replicate this on the desktop Stack Overflow site.

[image: After entering a tag]

The code on SO isn't exactly the same, though the symptom is.

Here's the actual code called after the text is inserted into the text field.

```
$(field).focus()[0].setSelectionRange(newCaretPos, newCaretPos);
```

<sub>(Yes yes, setSelectionRange is non-standard; but it works on all the mobile devices I care about just this moment, so ignore it for now)</sub>

On android, iphone, etc. this works fine (the keyboard "flickers" but I'm willing to live with it.

So, the question basically boils down to: How can I force the onscreen keyboard to appear on Windows Phone 7 (Mango update)?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no guaranteed way to force the SIP to display in WP7. :(

Answer (score 0):

Normally setting the focus on the textbox would force the keyboard. Have you tried just setting the focus? (i.e. not setting the selection range)

Comment: Yes, setting focus as part of a "dismiss the keyboard" event (like clicking anything while the keyboard is visible) presents the same problem, the keyboard is not displayed.